# Application Loader not showing option to import inAppPurchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, itunes, application-loader

I have a weird case, I have application loader 3.7 and I want to use to upload a mass of in-app Purchase items to iTunes. But to my astonishment the the button for import and the one for in-app purchase no longer shows on the application loader as shown in the screenshot.

I tried loading previous version 3.1, but same problem occurred.

What could be wrong with the program, and is there any alternative for submitting the items?

[image]

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Any updates?

Comment: No I found an older version on another pc so I'm using, but it's very weird, why the import option for inapp purchase has disappeared.

Comment: The older version is not functional, it contains a bug. I tried everything possible, kindly advise.

Comment: I'm starting a bounty of my own on this question.

Comment: @coder thanks! care to mark me as answer this way this question is marked as resolved?

Comment: Hi coder. Please do not roll back good edits here. Greetings (whether or not they are correctly spelled) and thanks do not belong on Stack Overflow. There is a [canonical reference on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Apple team they have assured that there is no current way to upload a bulk of in-app purchase on iTunes but instead they have suggested that we create a set of items based on their price.

For example, we sell eBooks so we have created items like eBook1 that stands for all books that cost 1$ and eBook2 for all books that cost 2$...

Comment: I have restored the edit from @WaiHaLee in this post. Material that expresses the sentiment of "hope it helps" is nice, but is not the kind of technical writing preferred on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, hope-it-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but unfortunately the only solution is for Apple to roll out a fix.

It's a bug on the iTunes end.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's resolved, I think there are alternatives that I'm currently searching for, but I'm very thankful, that you tried to contribute.